# JAX-RS 2: using Guava ListenableFuture for async resources

Tags: java, web-services, rest, asynchronous, jax-rs

Writing an asynchronous endpoint in JAX-RS 2 usually looks like this:

```
@GET
public void asyncGet(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String result = veryExpensiveOperation();
            asyncResponse.resume(result);
        }

        private String veryExpensiveOperation() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // ignore
            }
            return "DONE";
        }
    }).start();
}
```

However, this method is not very nice since it is not declarative. I have seen in some JAX-RS applications that it is possible to use Google Guava and write code like this:

```
ListeningExecutorService executor = ...;

@GET
public ListenableFuture<String> asyncGet() {
    return executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // ignore
            }
            return "DONE";
        }
    });
}
```

However, I don't know how to set up a JAX-RS 2 implementation to accept this kind of endpoint, and I haven't figured out how other implementations have done it.

How would I configure e.g. Jersey to accept this kind of asynchronous declaration?

Answer (score 1):

Resume the `asyncRresponse` in a [FutureCallback](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained#Adding_Callbacks):

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public void asyncGet(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
    ListenableFuture<String> future = asyncGet();
    Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            asyncResponse.resume(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable exception) {
            asyncResponse.resume(exception);
        }
    });
}
```

Make sure that asynchronous requests are enabled in your servlet configuration in the `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    ...
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

and that you use servlet 3.0 API.

Comment: This is technically the correct answer, but I would like this to be automatic. The code with `Futures.addCallback` will look exactly the same in every handler, so it would be nicer if one could inject a provider that does this automatically for every endpoint that returns a `ListenableFuture`

Comment: @dflemstr Now I get what you need. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it automatically.

Comment: @dflemstr did you ever figure out how to do this automatically? Also, do you know how this could be done using springs ListenableFuture implementation?

Comment: @LukaszWiktor: when I tried to add the <async-supported>true</async-supported> in web.xml it shows following error:
"cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'init-param'. One of '{"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":run-as, "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":security-role-ref, "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/
 javaee":multipart-config}' is expected." 

How to fix such case?

Comment: @Milson What servlet version is defined in your web.xml? `async-supported` is available as of 3.0

Comment: <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
.............
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
async-supported comes after load-on-startup
I think you forgot to mention the ordering of a good formatted web.xml

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a way to do what you are trying to do, but a cleaner solution would be to create a generic callback class:

```
class GenericFutureCallback<T> implements ListenableFutureCallback<T> {

        private AsyncResponse asyncResponse;
        private Response.Status status;

        public GenericFutureCallback(AsyncResponse asyncResponse, Response.Status status) {
            this.asyncResponse = asyncResponse;
            this.status = status;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            asyncResponse.resume(ex);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(T result) {
            Response response = Response.status(status).entity(result).build();
            asyncResponse.resume(response);
        }

    }
```

Then your controller would look like this:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public void asyncGet(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
    ListenableFuture<String> future = asyncGet();
    GenericFutureCallback<String> callback = new GenericFutureCallback<String>(asyncRes, Response.Status.OK);
    Futures.addCallback(future, callback);
}
```